# Google Sheets - toggling chart visibility

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any chance to toggle chart visibility?

Just annoying the empty Chart with big "NO DATA".

Have a nice Sunday!

Comment: not possible by standard means

Comment: This is not possible unless you use some workaround (mainly involving Apps Script). What would be the objective of toggling the visibility? Maybe one of those workarounds might work for you.